# How to filter XMLTABLE using data from existing table?

Tags: xml, oracle

I have a table d(col1,name,col3...coln) and xmlfile and i need to select from XML only that names, that dont exists in DB:

```
Select t.nam
From XMLTABLE('/Документ/План/СтрокиПлана/Строка' 
PASSING xml COLUMNS nam Varchar2(256) PATH '@Дис') t
    ,disciplines_ d
Where d.Name != t.nam;
```

but resulting output shows something that looks like

```
Select *
From table_1
    ,table_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try the following:

```
Select t.nam
  From XMLTABLE('/Документ/План/СтрокиПлана/Строка' 
       PASSING xml COLUMNS nam Varchar2(256) PATH '@Дис') t
 where t.nam NOT IN (SELECT d.name 
                       FROM disciplines_ d 
                      WHERE d.name IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Tnx for this idea, it works as i need. But anyway kinda strange that you cant just type a != b.

Comment: @behunter: your join clause would match each row from A to all rows from B that are different, this would effectively return nearly the same amount of rows as the cartesion join AxB